# How to use regular expression or like keyword to query information in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called phones with a column like this where items here are repeated

| brand |
| --- |
| Google |
| Samsung |
| Apple |
| Hydrogen |
| Nokia |
| Itel |
| Honor |
| Huawei |

and I want to use either the LIKE keyword or the regular expression in MySQL to get result that returns only `Hydrogen` and `Honor` in the `brand` column of the table. I have tried the following

```
select distinct brand from phones where brand like 'h%o%r';
```

but it returned only `Honor` instead of both. I'm trying to write a query that starts with 'H' and can have letter 'o', 'r' and even 'n' if possible that take any position, not necessarily in order, as is the case with `Hydrogen` and `Honor`.
I also tried `select distinct brand from phones where brand like 'h%(o|r)';` and it gave an empty set. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the logic to only select those two rows? Your idea sounds very bad and can have a horrible performance. You will do better to explain what you are trying to do and think about a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution to above mentioned issue,please try executing following SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `phones` where brand like 'h%' and brand like '%o%' and brand like '%r%'
```

Into above query we have used SQL wildcard characters with LIKE operator to match a pattern in a column.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve **all the rows** from the `phones` table where the `brand` column contains the letters “H”, “o”, and “r” in **any order**, you can use multiple `LIKE` operators combined with the `AND` operator:

```sql
SELECT brand FROM phones WHERE brand 
LIKE '%H%' AND brand LIKE '%o%' AND brand LIKE '%r%';
```

This query uses the `LIKE` function of the `%` wildcard character to find the row with the specified character in the `brand` column. The `AND` operation is used to ensure that all three conditions are satisfied.

If your database system **supports regular expressions**, you can also use a `REGEXP` function with more complex regular expressions to achieve the same result. Here is an example query that uses the `REGEXP` function to find rows where the `brand` column contains the letters “H”, “o” and “r” in any order:

```sql
SELECT * FROM phones WHERE brand 
REGEXP '(?=.*H)(?=.*o)(?=.*r)';
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the root of the question, you'd like to return only the records with **Hydrogen** or **Honor** as the brand. Is there a specific reason you need to use the LIKE operator? Sounds like you can do this a couple of ways:

1. Use the IN operator:

select * from phones where brand IN ('Hydrogen','Honor')

2. Use the OR operator:

select * from phones where (brand = 'Hydrogen' OR brand = 'Honor')

Let me know if these work!